# SimpleMembership MVC 4 get data from UserProfile having role in webpages_Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code.  But there must be a more database efficient way to do this, because, correct me if Im wrong the number of database queries is 
(1 + (qty of users with admin role))

With a new MVC 4 project the membership defaults are the tables UserProfile, webpages_Roles and webpages_UsersInRoles.  I see lots of built in methods for Roles.Get*.  If I want to avoid writing code like what I have below do I need to explicitly create a model for webpages_Roles and webpages_UsersInRoles as well as all the code first properties?  Getting just the username from Roles.Get* doesnt suffice, I need the full UserProfile.

FYI the "UserRole" object below is just an enum

```
public ActionResult Admins()
    {
        var dbContext = new UsersContext();
        var usernames = Roles.GetUsersInRole(UserRole.SiteAdministrator.ToString());
        var adminUsers = new List<UserProfile>();
        foreach (string username in usernames)
        {
            var adminUser = dbContext.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.ToLower() == username);
            adminUser.Roles.Add(UserRole.SiteAdministrator);
            adminUsers.Add(adminUser);
        }

        return View(adminUsers);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you don't want to do it that way.  That's a very inefficient way.

Instead, use the tools as they were designed.  For example, something like this:

```
var usernames = Roles.GetUsersInRole(UserRole.SiteAdministrator.ToString());

var adminUsers = dbContext.UserProfiles
     .Where(x => usernames.Contains(x.Username)).ToList();

return View(adminUsers);
```

Comment: With this code you provied, specifically "y => y == x.UserName" I get the error "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type. "

Comment: You need to add a `using System.Linq;` using statement

Comment: It was already there... and by default its there with MVC4 I think.

Comment: Then try this.  `y.Equals(x.UserName)`

Comment: same problem, there is something wrong with the "y" variable, there is no intellisense after it.  Also need to add another paren before the .ToList to close off the Where clause.

Comment: That's the problem.  The paren goes before .ToList(), see update.

Comment: Thats what I said about the paren, still the same problem.

Comment: @Marc - Ahh.. stupid mistake.  It should `usernames.Contains(x.UserName)`

Comment: Thanks, that works, don't forget to update your code in your answer.